# Updating library gives me Symbol(s) not found in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have this mobclix lib, I had an older version but I wanted to update it, I removed the old .a file and headers, and added the new ones, but I get the error message saying:

```
"_OBJ_CLASS_$_MobclixAdViewiPhone_320x50", referenced from:
Objc-class-ref-to-MobclixAdViewiPhone_320x50 in AdManager.o
Symbol(s) not found
Collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I Already have the lib in the target "linked libraries", did a clean, restarted xcode, and still I get the same error message.

This has occured in the past, and I didn't find any answer, I had to make a new project, but I think it's a waste of time.
Please help.

Comment: And nuked your build directory?

Comment: yep, I've deleted the build directory, no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MobclixAdViewiPhone_320x50 is not being found so you are not linking mobclix correctly. Got to love XCode: having the library in your target's "Link Binary With Libraries" section doesn't mean that the library will be linked. You must make sure that your target's **Build Settings > Library Search Paths** contains the correct path to the lib.

Comment: I see a mess of paths!, since I keep the old versions of the lib, it was like mixing the new headers with the old ".a" file, thank you a lot!, removed the old search paths and left only the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Completely delete the library from the Xcode project and then re-add it, along with re-adding it to your link phase.  Sounds like Xcode is stuck trying to link with a library that no longer exists.

Failing that:

1. Add a new build phase: Right click the target, Add -> New Build Phase -> New Copy Files Build Phase.
2. Set the destination to "Products Directory".
3. Drag your library into this build phase, and then;
4. (Important!) drag the position of the new build phase so it's ordered before the compile phase.

This is needed if the library isn't actually installed in a system path.  There are other ways to achieve the same effect, but this one is nice and portable.

Comment: I've deleted the lib from xcode and from the target's "link binary with libraries", then I create a new group and "add existing files" and add the new library, I made sure the lib is added to the target, but I get the same error.

Comment: Try this.  Add a new build phase: Right click the target, Add -> New Build Phase -> New Copy Files Build Phase. Set the destination to "Products Directory".   Drag your library into this build phase, and then (important!) drag the build phase so it comes *before* the compile phase.  Xcode should be better at using things from the project directory, but it's not unfortunately.  Copying the dependency to the build directory will give it a helping hand.